# Script add another script

Tags: javascript, php

I'm new to javascript and I have this issue. I have an array which I need to append inside my script tag, which means:

**Example:-**

```
array(abc=>'abc', def=>'def')

var markers = [
// putting the array here
]
```

In PHP I can just echo, but how can I achieve it in javascript? Furthermore, each time I click the button, it will call this function. Will it duplicate the variable markers each time I click?

Comment: @Epodax yes it has nothing to do with PHP but I just want to clarify using PHP works, but in javascript how does it going to work

Comment: @Epodax ok removed...

Comment: Arrays in Javascript are numerically indexed and not associative like they are ( can be ) in PHP. You could not directly translate your PHP array to a Javascript array but you could of course convert it to JSON notation so that `markers` became an object - thereby preserving the name to value relations

Answer (score 0):

Use Array.push like so: `markers.push('test')`. See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/push